# django url not working except admin

Tags: django, django-urls

hi guys my django app urls are not working
below is my project urls.py

```
     urlpatterns = patterns('',

           url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
            url(r'^', include('recipe.urls', namespace="recipe")),

    )
```

and here is my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url


urlpatterns = patterns('recipe.views',

    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    url(r'^create/recipe/$', 'create_recipe', name='create_recipe'),
    url(r'^create/ingredients/(?P<recipe_id>\d+)/$', 'create_ingredients', 
    name="create_ingredients"),
    url(r'^create/steps/(?P<recipe_id>\d+)/$', 'create_steps', 
    name="create_steps"),
     url(r'^view/recipe/(?P<recipe_id>\d+)/$', 'view_recipe', 
    name="view_recipe"),
)
```

I am not able to get the index page and other urls except admin is working fine. Please help me

Comment: what error is it showing? does it say the view does not exist?

Comment: if i say http://localhost:8000/

am getting templatedoesnt exists base.html

Comment: It is none of urls.py's business.

Comment: this base.html is included in any of your templates? otherwise does base.html exist in the "templates" folder, and is the "templates" folder correctly defined in the settings.py file?

Comment: in my project i have templates folder. in that base.html is there. and in my app folder also i have templates folder. in that i  have index.html

Comment: Then check settings.TEMPLATES_DIRS

Comment: os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates') is this not correct?. and i have extended base.html file in index.html as {% extend 'base.html' %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question comments it seems you are having issues with Django's templates instead of urlconfig. Here is how Django templates work. In your `settings.py` you define a variable `TEMPLATES_DIRS` where you specify a tuple of all directories where Django will look for templates.

Assume you have the following `TEMPLATES_DIRS`:

```
TEMPLATES_DIRS = (
    '/absolute/path/to/foo',
    '/absolute/path/to/bar',
)
```

Then if you look for a template `base.html`, Django will look for it in the following places and will use the first location if it finds one:

```
/absolute/path/to/foo/base.html
/absolute/path/to/bar/base.html
```

In your case you mentioned that you store your templates in both the Django's project folder as well as the app's folder. In that case you have to make sure that both folders are defined in `TEMPLATES_DIRS` like:

```
TEMPLATES_DIRS = (
    '/absolute/path/to/project/templates',
    '/absolute/path/to/app/templates',
)
```

Then in your case Django will be able to find both `base.html` and `index.html`. Now to make things simpler you can define `PROJECT_PATH` in your `settings.py` which will store the absolute path to your project path so that you can easily move your project to a different location. I think this is where your issue might be. In Django >= 1.4, you have the following project structure:

```
/project         <= this should be your PROJECT_PATH
  /project       <= instead of this
    templates/
      base.html
    settings.py
  /recipe
    templates/
      index.html
    models.py
```

With that in mind try using something like this:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..'))
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, PROJECT_NAME, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'recipe', 'templates')
)
```

In the above PROJECT_PATH calculates the absolute path of the project. Imagine that your `settings.py` is located at `/some/path/project/project/settings.py`. Then you compute the project path as follows:

```
>>> # settings.py

>>> print __file__
/some/path/project/project/settings.py
>>> print os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..')
/some/path/project/project/settings.py/../../
>>> # now abspath normalizes the path two levels up
>>> print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..'))
/some/path/project

>>> # now you figure out the project name so that you can get the project templates folder
>>> print os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..')))
project

>>> print os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, PROJECT_NAME, 'templates')
/some/path/project/project/templates
>>> print os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'recipe', 'templates')
/some/path/project/recipe/templates
```

Comment: hey miki thanks a lot it worked :) btw can you please explain what these two statements do

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..'))
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(PROJECT_PATH)

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py`, find and edit this -

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "templates"),
)
```